# Can't run libgdx project from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, libgdx

I have eclipse luna on win 8.1 and installed libgdx and there are no errors, but when I try to run my project I get this text:

Prints the ASM code to generate the given class.
Usage: ASMifier [-debug]

What's that and how to solve it?

Comment: A tip: Start using `Android Studio`, it works like a charm with the `LibGDX` framework. There is a small learning curve to set everything up like you want but `Android Studio` basically takes care of everything. I also converted to `AS` since a question about `LibGDX` with `Eclipse` here on `SO` and I am very thankful for that. `AS` has a ton of handy features and shortcuts. When things are not set up correctly you can often just click the error message and it will miraculously fix itself. It will become the standard if it is not already.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yes, I'll for sure try AS, but now I'm in the middle of my project so I would like to finish it first and start next one in AS (probably).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Under "Run as" wrong default was set. I'm actually not 100% sure why was I'm getting this message so clarification is welcome, but problem is not appearing any more.